# Using ratios and the numerator as explanatory variables in regression analysis with fixed effects

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interpretation, economics

I am running a fixed effects regression analysis with a ratio of number of sellers per capita and the number of sellers as explanatory variable on its own. How should I interpret the results?

My model looks as follows:

$ln(price) = \beta_0 + \beta_1ln(\frac{no.sellers}{capita}) + \beta_2ln(no.sellers) + controls$

I am in doubt how to interpret my results:

beta1: -0.05289

beta2: 0.04987

I'm trying to measure both the relative effect of more competitors per capita on price and the absolute effect of more sellers. Does it make sense at all to make this regression? I'm guessing that the total effect from sellers will be $\beta_1 + \beta_2$, since the above equation is equivalent to

$ln(price) = \beta_0 + \beta_1(ln(no.sellers) - ln(capita)) + \beta_2ln(no.sellers) = \beta_0 + \beta_1ln(no.sellers) - \beta_1ln(capita) + \beta_2ln(no.sellers) = \beta_0 + (\beta_1 + \beta_2)ln(no.sellers) - \beta_1ln(capita)$

What is your suggestions and interpretations?

Looking forward to all your great answers!